# Haskell: Multiple Actions in Single Case

Tags: haskell, io

I am trying to get IO functions within Haskell to send a variable up the IO to use within the main of the program. The specific part below is the main part giving me grief.

```
getInformation :: Int -> [String] -> IO [String]
getInformation input db
    |input == 1 = return (inputOne db)
    |input == 2 = return (inputTwo db)
    |input == 3 = return (inputThree db)
    |input == 4 = return (inputFour db)
    |input == 5 = return (inputFive db)
    |input == 6 = return (inputSix db)
    |input == 7 = return (inputSeven db)
    |input == 8 = return (inputEight db)
```

inputOne ... inputEight all return a value of IO [String] and I am trying to have the return be based on [String] rather than IO [String].
Ideally I want to try something like this for each case but I'm not sure how to go about this:

```
db2 <- (inputOne db)
return (db2)
```

I have tried doing experiments along the lines of:

```
|input == 1 = {db2 <- (inputOne db)
               return (db2)}
```

However, this would error and not work even though I believe that is along the right lines.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do `inputOne`, `inputTwo` etc. do? You're doing something wrong if you need eight different functions for eight cases.

Comment: They perform various IO actions depending on input chosen and sometimes change the value that they return.

Comment: If you do really actually need 8 different functions here you could reduce your typing a lot with `getInformation input db = ([inputOne, inputTwo, inputThree, ..., inputEigth] !! pred input) db`, obviously filling in the rest of the list.  Be careful that you don't pass it `9` for `input`, otherwise it would result in a runtime error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a do-block, you need the actual `do` keyword:

```
| input == 1 = do db2 <- inputOne db; return db2
```

You could also structure it like

```
| input == 1 = do
  db2 <- inputOut db
  return db2
```

if you prefer.

Notice that putting the result into a variable and immediately returning the same thing is the same as

```
| input == 1 = inputOne db
```